# dojo tutorial: dojo is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I want to get startet with dojo.

Therefore I am useing their tutorials: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/hello_dojo/

The simplest tutorial displays this page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tutorial: Hello Dojo!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="greeting">Hello</h1>
    <!-- load Dojo -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.1/dojo/dojo.js"
               data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I now open the page (tried both localy and hosted version on their page).
And when I write

```
dojo.query("h1")
```

in my firebug console I get the message:

> ReferenceError: dojo is not defined

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are your sure your source for dojo is in "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.1/dojo/dojo.js" because your folder structure look like in googleapis folder which is "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.1/dojo/dojo.js"

Comment: That is called a [protocol-relative URL](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) and will work just fine. No error there.

Comment: When I use the full url and replace line 10 and 11 with:

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

firefox loads dojo.js and I can enter dojo.query("h1") sucesfully in the console. Thank you ;)

Should work with the protocol-relative URL but for me it did not

Answer (score 7):

This question is lacking a correct answer. The reason this is not working is because you enabled `async` mode. What this actually does is that the Dojo core will be loaded asynchronously.

The **Dojo core** is the part of Dojo that is loaded automatically when you load the `dojo.js` file. It sets a global variable called `dojo` which contains basic functionality like the `dojo.query` part.

Your problem is that you're actually not waiting for the core to load. Because the core is not loaded, `dojo` will be `undefined`, giving you that error.

---

You should only use `async` mode when using the AMD loader (`require()`), if you don't want to use it (legacy mode), you just put `async` to `false`. But this mode is actually **deprecated** and will be removed in Dojo 2.0.

The other solution is to use the AMD loader (asynchronous module loader), the proper syntax to this is:

```
require([ "dojo/query" ], function(query) {
    query("h1");
});
```

In this example you might have the chance that the DOM is not loaded yet, so the best answer is to wait for the DOM to load as well, resulting in:

```
require([ "dojo/query", "dojo/domReady!" ], function(query) {
    query("h1");
});
```

---

You're indicating that it's working when you use the protocol implied URL. However, this is not true. The only reason why it suddenly is working is because you left the `async` property away, which defaults to `false`.

Unlike [Christofer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14599019/1915448) said, the legacy mode is still available, but it's deprecated.

[Agnes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18240285/1915448) will work because because it's using the AMD loader. However, combining legacy code and the new syntax doesn't look well. If you're choosing for AMD you should put everything in AMD and not only certain parts.

Answer (score 3):

Having no previous experience of Dojo, I read through a bit of the documentation. Especially [this part](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/modern_dojo/), talking about the "Modern Dojo".

It turns out, as of version 1.7, you can no longer just load dojo.js and expect to call `dojo.something`. With the "new Dojo", that is no longer possible. This is why you get `dojo is not defined`.

For more info, read through the updated documentation on how to get started, but here is a simple hello world:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tutorial: Hello Dojo!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../resources/style/demo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="greeting">Hello</h1>
    <!-- load dojo and provide config via data attribute -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="isDebug:1, async:1"></script>
    <script>
        require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"], function(dom){
            var greeting = dom.byId("greeting");
            greeting.innerHTML += " from Dojo!";
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you like to use the old way, I guess you could reference a version of Dojo prior to 1.7, but using a legacy version is rarely a good way forward, so I recommend that you learn the new way of doing things instead.

Comment: Thaks for pointing that out! Indeed the "modern dojo" tutorial tells that you should not use not use commands that go like dojo.* because these commands are deprecheated.

As I have understood they should work with a warning till 2.0 nontheless

Comment: @RCK69 Okay, that might very well be the case. Haven't used Dojo myself, so I don't know. I just noticed that when I used the way you loaded dojo, with the above hello world-example. It worked, while using `dojo.` caused an exception.

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-   config="async: true"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script>
require(["dojo"], function(dojo){
dojo.ready(function(){  
//Your code here
});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```